# removed autopublish and insecure: now i can't retrive data by MongoDB

Tags: meteor

I'm starting to learn Meteor.js and, when I've removed autopublish and insecure, my application doesn't work any longer.
I can insert data to database but I can't retrive anything by database.
No errors in console.
This is my code:

client/main.html

```
<head>
    <title>Blog Test</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Blog Test</h1>
    {{>blog}}
    {{>ListBlogs}}
</body>

<template name="blog">
    <form class="blog-post" id="blog-post" role="form">
        <label id="label-title" class="label-title">Titolo:</label>
        <input id="input-title" class="input-title" placeholder="Titolo">
        <br>
        <label id="label-text" class="label-text">Testo:</label>
        <textarea id="input-text" class="input-text" placeholder="Testo"></textarea>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="blog-btm">Submit</button>
    </form>
</template>
<template name="ListBlogs">
    {{#each posts}}
        <h2>{{title}}</h2>
        <p>{{text}}</p>
    {{/each}}
</template>
```

client/main.js

```
Template.blog.events({
  'submit #blog-post':function (e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var title = $('.input-title').val();
    var text = $('.input-text').val();
    Meteor.call('submitPost',title,text);
  }
});
Meteor.subscribe('posts');
```

server/server.js

```
Meteor.methods({
    'submitPost':function(title, text){
        console.log("Titolo: " + title);
        console.log("Testo:" + text);
        Blogs.insert({title:title, text:text});

    }
});

Meteor.publish('posts', function() {
return Blogs.find();
});
```

lib/blog.js

```
Blogs = new Meteor.Collection('blogs');
```

Comment: Where's your code to retrieve items from "posts"?

Answer (score 1):

We fixed this in IRC I believe :-)
The problem is that your template `ListBlogs`has no idea what `posts` means. You will have to define a helper, so that the `{{#each posts}}` block gets a meaning.

Fortunately this only requires a very quick fix:

```
Template.ListBlogs.posts = function(){
    return Blogs.find().fetch();
}
```

Put this in your `client/main.js` and all posts appear in realtime.

Comment: The `.fetch()` is not necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

your code it's ok, though you must to try subscribe on collection of this way

```
Tracker.autorun(function () {
  Meteor.subscribe("posts");
});
```

http://docs.meteor.com/#tracker_autorun

and after that you must to create the helpers, for example...

```
Template.blog.helpers({

})


Template.ListBlogs.helpers({
    posts: function(){
       return Posts.find({});
    }
})
```